# Where is the value in the lambda function coming from?

Tags: python, python-3.x

below is the code part from this github [repo](https://github.com/sebasutp/promp) that I am confused of:

full_promp.py:

```
.....
......
class ProbInvKinematics:
    #params:
    #fwd_k: A forward kinematics object

    def __laplace_cost_and_grad(self, theta, mu_theta, inv_sigma_theta, mu_x, inv_sigma_x):
        
        print ("theta ",theta)
        f_th, jac_th, ori = self.fwd_k.position_and_jac(theta)
        jac_th = jac_th[0:3,:]
        diff1 = theta - mu_theta
        tmp1 = np.dot(inv_sigma_theta, diff1)
        diff2 = f_th - mu_x
        tmp2 = np.dot(inv_sigma_x, diff2)
        
        nll = 0.5*(np.dot(diff1,tmp1) + np.dot(diff2,tmp2))
        
        grad_nll = tmp1 + np.dot(jac_th.T,tmp2)
        
        return nll, grad_nll

    def __init__(self, fwd_kinematics):
        self.fwd_k = fwd_kinematics

    def inv_kin(self, mu_theta, sig_theta, mu_x, sig_x):
        inv_sig_theta = np.linalg.inv(sig_theta)
        inv_sig_x = np.linalg.inv(sig_x)
        cost_grad = lambda theta: self.__laplace_cost_and_grad(theta, mu_theta, inv_sig_theta, mu_x, inv_sig_x)
        cost = lambda theta: cost_grad(theta)[0]
        grad = lambda theta: cost_grad(theta)[1]
        res = opt.minimize(cost, mu_theta, method='BFGS', jac=grad)
        post_mean = res.x
        post_cov = res.hess_inv
        return post_mean, post_cov
```

Usage of the class `ProbInvKinematics` as follow:

```
import robpy.full_promp as promp

prob_inv_kin = promp.ProbInvKinematics(fwd_kin)
mu_cartesian = np.array([-0.62, -0.44, -0.34])
Sigma_cartesian = 0.02**2*np.eye(3) 
mu_q, Sigma_q = prob_inv_kin.inv_kin(mu_theta=prior_mu_q, sig_theta=prior_Sigma_q,
        mu_x = mu_cartesian, sig_x = Sigma_cartesian)
```

I see that the parameter value `theta` is defined nowhere. But somehow when I try to print out `theta` in `def __laplace_cost_and_grad()`, the value is there... What is the logic of using this `theta`?

Comment: Presumably `opt.minimize` (which receives the functions as arguments) knows they take exactly one argument, corresponding to `theta`, and passes that single argument in, which gets received under the name `theta` (I have no idea what `opt.minimize` does, so where it gets `theta` from I don't know).

Comment: `theta` *is* defined - it is the name of the first parameter to the lambda function.  Same as if you had created a named function like `def cost_grad(theta): ...`.  The *value* of `theta` is whatever the caller passes in to that first parameter (which happens inside of the `opt.minimize` function).

Comment: What do you mean `theta` isn't defined anywhere? **The parameter defines it**. It obtains the value when it is called from its argument.

Comment: `def __laplace_cost_and_grad(self, theta, mu_theta, inv_sigma_theta, mu_x, inv_sigma_x):`.  As mentioned by other comments `thetha` is there first argument after self

Comment: `cost = lambda theta: cost_grad(theta)[0]` ---> `cost = lambda theta: (self.__laplace_cost_and_grad(theta, mu_theta, inv_sig_theta, mu_x, inv_sig_x))[0]`